# How do I create a free C# development environment

Tags: installation, development-environment

For personal projects I cannot use my work-licence of Visual Studio Professional at home.

Visual Studio Express just seem less appealing than the professional edition, what are my alternatives except notepad?

Comment: "less appealing" in what way? Which specific features does it lack that you require?

Answer (score 3):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) are only two options, though even the Express edition of Visual Studio seems to have more features (and is more familiar to those using the Pro/Ultimate editions).

A number of programming text editors have C# syntax highlighting and you can invoke the compiler with key bindings (that you will need to configure yourself), though a dedicated IDE would make a better experience. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is one such editor.

Answer (score 1):

`Notepad++`? :)

More seriously though, there are free C# IDE's out there, such as [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) however I have always preferred Visual Studio myself.

Answer (score 1):

One open source alternative is [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/).

Edit: And as Kyle pointed out, I too prefer Visual Studio above anything else.